# Catching NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, gcc, gnustep

I've been toying around with Objective-C + GNUstep on Linux lately, but I can't understand why this code snippet doesn't work the way I think it should.  Sending the talk message to pet causes an NSInvalidArgumentException to be thrown like I'd expect, but for some reason it doesn't get handled by the catch block.  Is there something I'm missing, or are these sorts of exceptions supposed to be un-catchable?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>

@interface Dog : NSObject
{
}
-(void) speak;
@end

@implementation Dog
-(void) speak
{
    NSLog(@"arf!\n");
}
@end

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Dog *pet = [Dog alloc];

    [pet speak];
    @try {
        [pet talk];
    }@catch (id error) {
        NSLog(@"Dogs can\'t do that, silly!");
    }

    [pet release];

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler flags:

```
gcc -fgnu-runtime -fobjc-exceptions -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString crash.m -lobjc -lgnustep-base -g
```

Output:

```
jay@localhost ~/programs/objc/why $ ./a.out
2014-05-08 17:07:05.169 a.out[20341] arf!
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x18ae4c0) of class GSCInlineString in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x18afd70) of class NSException in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x1851000) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x1850dc0) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x1850ab0) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x184e7d0) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x1850ca0) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x184ec50) of class NSIntNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x184e620) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
2014-05-08 17:07:05.170 a.out[20341] autorelease called without pool for object (0x1850c10) of class NSIntNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x17a5ee0>
./a.out: Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[Dog talk]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1818ef0
```

Comment: Just so you know, the `@catch` *is* used under OSX 10.9 with `clang` 5.1.1, and the error message " -[Dog talk]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb6f3d02e50" is produced.

Comment: NapoleonBlownapart, have you fixed the issue?